# Is changing SITE_ID dynamically in middleware considered good idea?

Tags: django, settings, middleware, django-middleware, django-settings

(this isn't duplicate of ["Changing Django settings variable dynamically based on request for multiple site"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380020/changing-django-settings-variable-dynamically-based-on-request-for-multiple-site), as that previous question covers making much more serious reconfiguration at runtime)

I use `sites.Site` to tie content to domains/host in my project (via foreign key). Choosing appropriate `Site` based on `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` takes place in my custom middleware.

However, I'm aware that such use of `sites` framework isn't exactly The Canonical Way (I have **one** instance of application serving different data for different domains, while `sites` - AFAIK - was designed to work with **several** instances, one per each domain).

Element that bothers me the most is `settings.SITE_ID` - static setting that ties current instance of application with one `Site` (domain). This is used in several places, i.e. `contrib.auth` (to compose full, absolute url in password reset email).
So, it would be cool to dynamically change `SITE_ID` based on `request.META['HTTP_HOST']`.

So my question is:

**Is changing SITE_ID dynamically (i.e. in middleware) considered a good idea?**

Documentation states that altering settings at runtime is generally bad idea ([here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime)), but perhaps doing it in this case (in middleware called early enough) is fine.

(edit):

It works as expected locally (Django test client), but I'm considering concurrent requests in production environment with multiple threads and/or processes.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you actually tried it? Seems like you're hinting that you have indeed tried it. I'm curious as to what was the results.

Comment: @Nimmy Lebby: Yeah, I've tried it locally (custom middleware - first on `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list takes care of setting SITE_ID), done some unit tests (using Django test client) as well. I'm considering production wsgi environment - concurrent requests with multithread/multiprocess concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just turn off `django.contrib.sites`? If you remove that from `INSTALLED_APPS`, you should be fine.

Specifically, any well-written apps should now be using the `get_current_site` function from `django.contrib.sites.models`. When the sites app isn't installed, this function will just return an instance of a `RequestSite` object (not a model) which works similarly to a standard Site instance.

To answer the original question though, **editing settings dynamically is *never* a good idea**.

Comment: hmm, that approach seems OK (RequestSite does have `domain` parameter obtained internally via `get_host`), I'll check this later and return with feedback ;) Thanks for now.